# Create a view in sql server using dynamic sql inside

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this sounds weird, but is it possible to have a view that use dynamic SQL to build it? I know the views are compiled so most probably this is not possible. For sure I could do it using an stored procedure instead but I just want to make sure is not possible.

Here I have an example:

```
declare @Table1 as table (
 Id int,
 Name nvarchar(50),
 Provider nvarchar(50)
)

insert @Table1 values (1, 'John', 'Provider1')
insert @Table1 values (2, 'Peter', 'Provider1')
insert @Table1 values (3, 'Marcus', 'Provider2')

declare @Table2 as table (
 Id int,
 Info nvarchar(50),
 AnotherInfo nvarchar(50)
)

insert @Table2 values (1, 'Expense', '480140')
insert @Table2 values (1, 'Maintenance', '480130')
insert @Table2 values (2, 'Set Up Cost', '480150')
insert @Table2 values (2, 'Something', '480160')

--No columns from Table2
select a.Id, a.Name, a.Provider from @Table1 a left join @Table2 b on a.Id = b.Id

--With columns from Table2
select a.Id, a.Name, a.Provider, b.Info, b.AnotherInfo from @Table1 a left join @Table2 b on a.Id = b.Id
```

The first select looks like I have repeated data, which is normal because I did the left join, the problem is that for avoiding that I need to perform a distinct and this is what I don't want to do. My example is short but I have much more columns and table is quite big.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, exactly, that would require this?  That might help facilitate an answer here.

I use dynamic SQL to create views all the time (and re-generate them as needed) so this works.  But the View itself is limited to being exactly one SELECT statement (or a UNION of selects), so you can't declare variables or have multiple statement in the body, so the view ITSELF can't create dynamic SQL.

Comment: Could what you want be provided by a [table-valued user-defined function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspxhttps://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx)? They're basically parameterised views that can have quite complex SQL inside them, but can be used in a FROM clause like a view...

Comment: How do you mean "use dynamic SQL to build it"?   Can you add an example to your question?

Comment: I guess it's not possible. I have already one view, I need to add a left join to a table so instead of modifying the current one I decided to create another view that does a left join between the first view and the table, why left join, because the table could have many records for one key. The purpose is a UI that user can select columns and create a report dynamically. The problem is that if none of the table columns are selected, looks like I have repeated data so I need to do a distinct that I don't want to.